# XHTML Setting line-breaks for multiple anchor tags with multiple images inside

Tags: css, xhtml, line-breaks

Considering this sample code:

```
<div style="width:300px;">
   <a href="#">
      <img src="images/bracket_open.png"/>
      <img src="images/1.png"/>
      <img src="images/bracket_close.png"/>
   </a>
   <a href="#">
      <img src="images/bracket_open.png"/>
      <img src="images/2.png"/>
      <img src="images/bracket_close.png"/>
   </a>
   <a href="#">
      <img src="images/bracket_open.png"/>
      <img src="images/3.png"/>
      <img src="images/bracket_close.png"/>
   </a>
</div>
```

Basically a long list of anchor tags that contain multiple image tags (because of the font) that make up something like `[1] [2] [3]` and so on.

How can I make it so that the line breaks only occur between the anchor tags and never between the image tags inside of the anchor tags.

I would preffer a XHTML/CSS solution rather than JavaScript if such exists.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple nowrap doesn't work?

```
div a {
    white-space:nowrap;
    }
```

With HTML like

```
<a href="#"><span>[</span><span>1</span><span>]</span></a><a href="#"><span>[</span><span>2</span><span>]</span></a><a href="#"><span>[</span><span>1</span><span>]</span></a>...
```

You also can use:

```
div a {
    float:left;
    white-space:nowrap;
    }
```

But it's not rather elegant due to making inline elements float with no weighty reason.

Comment: Any idea what the compatibility with browsers is for `white-space:nowrap;`?

Comment: Also, the problem I get now is that no wrapping happens whatsoever as there are no white spaces between anchor tags, they only have margin-left and margin-right.

Comment: It's kind of essential rule. I only recall some bug in IE when using both nowrap and left/right padding on an element.

Comment: Then, I guess, you need to provide a full code (both css and html). Better with absolute paths in imgs' src.

Comment: Hm, no what I meant was this code doesn't break at all now: `<a><img/></a><a><img/></a>` etc. Seeing as there are no spaces between `<a>` tags it doesn't break anymore. I suppose I could just add a space character to make it break, but is there a more elegant way?

Comment: I've updated my answer. May be someone will come with a more clear solution.